Decode missing scientist's last message
It was widely rumoured in the scientific community that Professor Kettleworth was trying to use her work on interchanging position and momentum operators to develop a working time machine.  The government was skeptical, but when she disappeared they sent agents in to investigate, as they would relish getting hold of a working time machine before their enemies.
All the agents could uncover, was a message Professor Kettleworth sent to her trusted assistant:



sg _ h r dvl _ u i bj _  _  _  cf tk pox _ _ w z an y _ _ _ _ _




bo _ _ _ w rn f _ dh _ c _ _ e l _ _ pv _ kati us _ _ _ _ _




_ a _ z _ w n _ xs _ i ut _ dy gok _ _ chl _ _ b p fr _ _ _



The assistant denied having any idea what this mysterious message meant and the agents were not able to find any of Professor Kettleworth's work, so they had to return empty handed.
What does the message say?
Hint 1:

 Professor Kettleworth and her assistant never discussed complex ciphers, so she needed to encode her message in a way that her assistant would be able to guess based on her knowledge of her.  That knowledge is included in the question.

Hint 2:

 What do the three lines of the message have in common?


_ _ _ a iu _ _ p ns _ _ _ ht d be _ _ _ jk for _ _ m _ _ _

@codewarrior0 l _ h _ i _  _  _  mad _  _ foe _ rn s _ _ j _ kt _ _ c _ p _

@codewarrior0 gx _ f _ cqunj _ _ b is _ _ y t v _ p _ rh ek law _ _ _ o _ _ , _ _ _ _ tomb _ _ l hr _ _ e _ ip _ _ _ sa c qfk d _ _ _ _ _ , _ _ qm _ or j _ a bn _ _ _ _ p ie _ _ f lc d _ _ _ _ g _
